# qt qml errors with QtQuick Dialogs 1

Tags: qt, qml

I"m using Qt 5.15.2. Below is the qml snippet that is failing for me.
Upon launching everything is ok. However when i try to open new windows, 1 window will be ok, but second (and subsequent) one will start showing something like this in the console.

```
bin/archdatadir/qml/QtQuick/Dialogs/DefaultFileDialog.qml:99: TypeError: Value is null and could not be converted to an object
bin/archdatadir/qml/QtQuick/Controls/SplitView.qml:630: TypeError: Property 'terminateItemConnections' of object QObject_QML_93(0x600003397f20) is not a function
bin/archdatadir/qml/QtQuick/Controls/SplitView.qml:630: TypeError: Property 'terminateItemConnections' of object QObject_QML_93(0x600003394500) is not a function
bin/archdatadir/qml/QtQuick/Dialogs/DefaultFileDialog.qml:436: TypeError: Cannot read property 'bottom' of undefined
....
```

If I remove the `FileDialog` definition completely, which is actually unused here, then these errors disappear completely. Would there be any suggestions on what I am doing incorrectly?

thanks!

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.4 
import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.2 

ApplicationWindow {
    id: root

    onClosing: {
        console.log("closing window")
    }   

    menuBar: MenuBar {
        Menu {
            title: qsTr("&File")

            MenuItem {
                text: qsTr("&New")
                icon.name: "document-new"
                onTriggered: newDocument()
            }   
        }   
    }   

    FileDialog {
        id: openDialog
        title: "Open"
        folder: shortcuts.home
        onAccepted: {
            console.log("open file dialog")
        }   
    }   

    function newWindow() {
        console.log("new window")
        var component = Qt.createComponent("reproducer.qml")
        var window = component.createObject()
        return window
    }   

    function newDocument() {
        console.log("new document")
        var window = newWindow()
        window.show()
    }   
}
```

VK

Comment: Replacing import of QtQuick.Diaglos 1.X with Qt.labs.platform 1.X solves the issue. From qt qml description it is written that QtQuick Dialogs is QtQuick Controls 1 module. Is there a problem mixing controls 2 with controls 1???

Comment: Where do you read that QtQuick.Dialogs is part of Quick Controls 1? It is not listed [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-controls-qmlmodule.html).

Comment: it's a bit confusing, but i was following this guy [qmlbook](https://qmlbook.github.io/ch06-controls/controls.html#introduction-to-controls) and comparison table in qt docs is showing it as part of qt quick controls 1 [qt qml docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquickcontrols2-differences.html#type-comparison-table) may be not part of it, but for some reason it's not something that is part of controls 2...

Comment: Yes, that is confusing. In general, no, there is no problem mixing Controls 1 & 2. You just have to be careful to avoid naming conflicts. I don't know why the QtQuick.Dialogs isn't working for you, but it looks like the Qt.labs version is newer anyway.